# DoDragDrop interfering with bindingsource

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok, I've got a bindingsource which represents a dataset.
That bindingsource is bound to a listbox. This works exactly as intended, in that it is populated with all the names from the specified column. Not a problem.

I've got a second listbox, bound to a different bindingsource1, which is itself bound to the bindingsource1, but using a datamember representing one of the relationships to a different table in the dataset. The upshot of this is that when I click an item in the first list, the second list displays all related stuff.

Nothing new, or indeed complex here, it's pretty standard stuff and works exactly as intended.

However, I'm trying to implement drag and drop functionality on the first list box. I've added an event handler for mousedown. Inside this, I'm calling

`DoDragDrop(current, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);`

where current is set to the current object from `bindingsource1.Current.Row["Name"]`.

Now, this is where it gets strange. Even though the listbox itself is updated correctly (in that the newly selected item is highlighted, index and item all return as expected, the newly selected item/ index) the bindingsource1.Current has NOT been updated, and indeed, the second list box still shows the data relevant to the previously selected item.

Using the arrow keys to move up and down causes the listbox highlight to change as expected, and also the data in listbox2 to be updated as expected.

Commenting out the DoDragDrop line and everything seems to work exactly as intended.

From this I can only infer that DoDragDrop is somehow preventing certain events from firing, but I've no idea why/ if this is desired behavior/ how to dirty work round it/ how to work round it properly...

Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope...

edit: I've created a simplified implementation of the problem: dropbox.com/s/qxfsvr28ftojdax/BindingDragDrop.zip Comment out the dodragdrop and the labels at the top change, put the dodragdrop in and it doesn't even register... –

Comment: Guesing without code to look at: exceptions are swallowed in D+D event handlers.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos for the repro code.  You can diagnose this by adding an event handler for the TextChanged event for the label and setting a breakpoint on it with DoDragDrop commented out.  Second time it breaks when you change the list selection look at the call stack.  You'll see that it is the *MouseUp event* that updated the binding list.

That's a problem when you call DoDragDrop in the MouseDown event.  The MouseUp event for the ListBox will no longer get fired, the notification gets swallowed by the D+D logic and cancels the drag.  A possible workaround is to update the binding explicitly so you don't have to rely on it happening automatically.  This worked:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    bindingSource1.Position = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    DoDragDrop(new object(), DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

Btw, problems like these is why I never use data binding in Winforms...

Comment: I hadn't spotted the Position attribute on the bindingsource - I'd attempted to do pretty much that with the Current attribute on the datasource, until I noticed that the current was read only.

Cheers for this! I am starting to learn that binding is certainly a double edged sword!